# How to get jquery object by its custom attribute

Tags: jquery

HTML segment:

```
<ul id="nav_des">
    <li class="cur">test1<a class="shopping2" data-category-id="1">12</a></li>
    <li>test2<a class="shopping2" data-category-id="2"></a></li>
    <li >test3<a class="shopping2" data-category-id="3"></a></li>
    <li style="margin-bottom:25px; background:none"></li>
</ul>
```

I want to get the text() of "" which "data-category-id" is 1 (i.e. it is 12 ) . I tried to use attribute selector like this but failed. So I just use "for" loop to get the value, but I don't think it's a good way. How to fix it? thanks

```
var category_id =1 
$(".shopping2").("data-category-id='"+category_id+"'").show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[attribute-equals-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)** to get elements by their attribute values:

```
$(".shopping2[data-category-id='"+category_id+"']").show();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L1417dgn/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap attributes like those in square brackets (the [attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors)):

```
$(".shopping2[data-category-id='"+category_id+"']").show();
```

This will select the element whose class is "shopping2" and whose `data-category-id` is equal to the `category_id` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this : You can use **[Attribute Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)** to select element with particular attribute value.

```
var category_id =1 
$(".shopping2[data-category-id='"+category_id+"']").show();
```